# How to change only one cell in list matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to create function that generates symbol canvas, and than paints on it according to instructions described in list:

```
def matrixPrinter(matrixWidth = 16, matrixHeight = 8, brush = 'X'):

    def createCanvas(width, height):
        canvas = []
        canvasRow = []
        for i in range(width):
            canvasRow.append('#')
        for i in range(height):
            canvas.append(canvasRow)
        return canvas

    def paintCoordinate(x, y):
        canvas[y][x] = brush

    # ------------------------------


    canvas = createCanvas(matrixWidth, matrixHeight)

    paintCoordinate(0,0) # This should paint first cell in first row

    for i in range(len(canvas)):
        canvas[i] = ''.join(canvas[i])
    canvas = '\n'.join(canvas)

    print(canvas)
matrixPrinter()
```

This is what i want to get in output:

```
X###############
################
################
################
################
################
################
################
```

But somehow i get this:

```
X###############
X###############
X###############
X###############
X###############
X###############
X###############
X###############
```

Why does it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are using the same list instance for each row, which causes that if you modify one, you end up modifying all of them. You need to create a new list for each one. And also you can create lists of the same item using *.

```
def createCanvas(width, height):
    canvas = []
    for i in range(height):
        canvasRow = ['#'] * width
        canvas.append(canvasRow)    
    return canvas
```

This concept is related to pointers and memory allocation, this topic is not that clear in python for beginners, as compared to in C. Here is further explanation related to your problem [An Introduction to Python Lists](http://www.effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every row in canvas refers to the same `canvasRow` object, and when you update the `X` on one row, All the other rows are updated as well with an `X` on the first row, since each row is referencing to the same list object.

You can also check this by printing `id` of every row in `canvas`, they are all the same

```
    def createCanvas(width, height):
        canvas = []
        canvasRow = []
        for i in range(width):
            canvasRow.append('#')
        for i in range(height):
            canvas.append(canvasRow)

        #Print id of columns
        for col in canvas:
            print(id(col))
        return canvas
```

The output will be

```
4326096840
4326096840
4326096840
4326096840
4326096840
4326096840
4326096840
4326096840
```

You can actually simplify your `createCanvas` by using list comprehension to create your 2D Canvas

```
def createCanvas(width, height):
    canvas =  [['#' for _ in range(width)] for i in range(height)]
    return canvas
```

Comment: I already got this and fixed by using `canvas.append(list(''.join(canvasRow)))`. Now everything works fine.

Comment: You don't even need `append` and `join` you can create your canvas in a single line using list-comprension @brachkoff Check my updated answer!